# shell script not found in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am new to hadoop and hadoop streaming so this error is probably something obvious that I miss.

I run an inline awk mapper command and it works fine.

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar -input input -output output -mapper "/usr/bin/awk -F'\t' '\$1==\"and\"'" -reducer NONE
```

However, when I put the awk command to a file and run it.  I got Java IOException on all machines in the cluster.

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar -input one_to_one/part* -output 4 -mapper test.sh -reducer NONE -file test.sh
```

test.sh

```
/usr/bin/awk -F '\t' '(NR == 1) {print NR,OFS,$0;}'
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/hadoop/tmp/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201207051227_0012/attempt_201207051227_0012_m_000000_0/work/./test.sh": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:214)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:91)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

1. Adding a hash/she-bang to your test.sh:

   `#!/bin/bash`
2. Amend -file to -files

   `hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar
        -input one_to_one/part* -output 4 -mapper test.sh -reducer NONE -files test.sh`